# Determine if mysql index is being used on production site, so it can be safely removed

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

We have some large indexes that we suspect are not being used in our Rails site, and would like to drop them to save space and computation. However, doing so could be catastrophic if it turns out they were being used. How can we confirm they are not being used?

One option is to log all queries for a time and run 'explain plan' on any of them that use the table in question. But I've heard 'explain plan' can occasionally be inaccurate. We would also have to collect queries for a few hours to be sure, which is quite a lot of log to store and process.

If there was a way to temporarily disable an index, we'd be willing to do that, as long as we could quickly enable it if problems arose. But I don't see a way to do that universally; you can only specify an 'ignore index' hint to individual sql statements.

Comment: Be careful not to solve a problem you don't actually have. Disk space is very cheap. Here's a list of tools you might use to dig into your system and figure out what kind of tuning will actually help your users.  http://www.percona.com/software

Comment: jet profiler always helped me with mysql optimizations (http://www.jetprofiler.com)

Comment: Ollie: We definitely have this problem, but it's more about memory than disk. Increasingly we can't keep everything in memory and swapping saps our performance. And even if storage was not a problem, we expend valuable database CPU maintaining these indexes on insert/update. And yes, our db server is large and maxed out and we're dealing with ~1 billion rows in our table.

Comment: Have you searched your code base for any usage of the field name? Or perhaps looked through DB migrations (if you are using such) to determine when index was added and any code changes that took place around that same time to understand what code might actually exist that utilizes said index? Do you have database dumps of the database that you might be able to replay say a day's worth of query traffic against?

Comment: This tool automates running `explain` on logged statements to find unused indexes, if you decide to go that way: http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-index-usage.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**:

With MySQL 5.6 it is possible to do this by using the `PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA` and [ps_helper](http://www.markleith.co.uk/ps_helper/).

ps_helper is a series of views and routines that present the data in `PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA` in more useful ways.  The VIEW you are after is this one: http://www.markleith.co.uk/ps_helper/#schema_unused_indexes

**More detailed:**

The idea of disabling an index is called 'invisible indexes' in Oracle.  MySQL doesn't support them, but I'd love to see this feature as well - I filed http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70299 a couple of months ago on it.

Removing unused indexes is very important, as it can help optimizer performance.  I have a war-story of using the ps_helper + unused_indexes view here: http://www.tocker.ca/2013/09/05/migrating-from-postgresql-to-mysql.html

Comment: Thanks Morgan! I also just read about INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INDEX_STATISTICS in Percona 5.6 - perhaps this is based on the same information?

Comment: More or less.  INDEX_STATISTICS/USER_STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS was a Google team invention for MySQL, which Percona adopted.  The MySQL team at the same time was developing their own standard (PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA).

Answer (score 0):

There's only one procedure for this: Testing, testing, testing and **benchmarking**.

The primary function of indexes, apart form ensuring uniqueness, is to expedite data access. If all operations were O(1) there would be no need for indexes in the first place.

You need to have another instance of your application where you can experiment with adding, removing, and adjusting your indexes. It's impossible to replicate both real-world hardware *and* real-world loads, but you can come pretty close if you pay careful attention to how your hardware is configured, how your application is exercised, and can produce that's reasonably similar.

If you have a application logs that are sufficiently detailed, sometimes you can replay these operations. Read operations are easier to replay than writes, but both can be simulated if you've got enough time to invest in this.

For any application running at scale, you want to know where performance falls off a cliff. So long as your production load is well below this level you'll be okay. If you don't know where the cliff is, you might hit it without any warning.

Remember that indexes not only take up space, which is a minor issue, but the size of the index has an effect on how expensive it is to update, making writes more costly. It's ideal to have only the ones you need, but it's almost impossible to identify which are *actually* used. There are many that might be used in theory, but never are, and some that shouldn't be used, but which are because the query optimizer is a little dumb sometimes.